# What's wrong with this code which saves every third character of a .txt file?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program which saves every third character of a .txt file. The text file's name used here is "Hello.txt" and it looks like this:

`ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`

Below is the code which I have tried:

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int ch;
    int count = 0;
    char name[20];
    FILE *fp, *out;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");  // argv[1] is "Hello.txt" 

    strncpy(name, argv[1], 5);  // Just copying "Hello"
    name[5] = '\0';              
    strcat(name, "red");        // Adding "red" to "Hello"

    out = fopen(name, "w");     // File pointer to "Hellored"

    while( ( ch=getc(fp) ) != EOF)  // Copying content of file "Hello.txt"
        if (count % 3 == 0)         // Only want to save every third character of "Hello.txt"
        {
            putc(ch, out);
            count++;
        }

}
```

As expected, it saves "Hellored" file in the workspace. But when I open it with adding ".txt" at the end of the file, the output is "A". What's wrong with this code?

Comment: put `count++` outside of the `if`

Comment: Remember to `fclose()` the files. Also check if the `fopen()` calls succeeded.

Comment: Kudos for providing a [mcve].

Comment: @RSahu Haha thanks R Sahu!

Comment: Warnings should not be disabled without good reason and only locally. What specifically do you suppress here? Remove that pragma, and state the warning (mark the postion in the code with a comment).

Comment: @Olaf Ok, the warning goes like this: `C4996 'fopen': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using fopen_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS ` and the same warning for `strncpy` and `strcat` functions. BTW, I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not incrementing `count` properly. It needs to be incremented for every character not just inside the `if` block.

```
while( ( ch=getc(fp) ) != EOF)  // Copying content of file "Hello.txt"
{
   if (count % 3 == 0)         // Only want to save every third character of "Hello.txt"
   {
      fputc(ch, out);
   }

   // Increment count for every character.
   count++;
}
```

Additional cleanup:

Add code to close the files before the end of the function.

```
fclose(out);
fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (count % 3 == 0)         // Only want to save every third character of "Hello.txt"
    {
        putc(ch, out);
        count++;
    }
```

You only increment `count` once.

The first time through the loop `count` is `0`, so the if body is executed.

On all subsequent times, `count` is `1` and the if body never executes again and `count` is never again incremented.

Move the increment outside the `if`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't increment `count` inside the `if`statement.

```
while( ( ch=getc(fp) ) != EOF) { //make sure you have {} around your while block
    if (count % 3 == 0) {
        putc(ch, out);
    }
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code the variable `count` is only incremented once (if `count == 0`). So the if statement only becomes true once (and after that `count` is alway 1)!

And you have to close the files with `fclose(fp)` and `fclose(out)` at the end of your program,
to ensure, that all of your data are written into the file!

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int ch;
    int count = 0;
    char name[20];
    FILE *fp, *out;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");  // argv[1] is "Hello.txt" 

    strncpy(name, argv[1], 5);  // Just copying "Hello"
    name[5] = '\0';              
    strcat(name, "red");        // Adding "red" to "Hello"

    out = fopen(name, "w");     // File pointer to "Hellored"

    while( ( ch=getc(fp) ) != EOF)  // Copying content of file "Hello.txt"
        if (count++ % 3 == 0)         // Only want to save every third character of "Hello.txt"
        {
            putc(ch, out);
        }
    fclose(out);
    fclose(fp);
}
```